# Binning in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have been unable to find a function in matlab or octave to do what I want.
I have a matrix m of two columns (x and y values).  I know that I can extract the column by doing m(:,1) or m(:,2).  I want to split it into smaller matricies of [potentially] equal size and and plot the mean of these matricies.  In other words, I want to put the values into bins based on the x values, then find means of the bins.  I feel like the hist function should help me, but it doesn't seem to.

Does anyone know of a built-in function to do something like this?

*edit*

I had intended to mention that I looked at hist and couldn't get it to do what I wanted, but it must have slipped my mind.

Example:  Let's say I have the following (I'm trying this in octave, but afaik it works in matlab):

```
x=1:20;
y=[1:10,10:1];
m=[x, y];
```

If I want 10 bins, I would like m to be split into:

```
m1=[1:2, 1:2]
...
m5=[9:10, 9:10]
m6=[10:11, 10:-1:9]
...
m10=[19:20, 2:-1:1]
```

and then get the mean of each bin.

Update: I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427221/better-non-linear-binning).  I would greatly appreciate responses.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, could you illustrate what you're saying with an example?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have answered this in video form on my blog:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/01/07/binning-data-in-matlab/

Here is the code:

```
m = rand(10,2); %Generate data

x = m(:,1); %split into x and y
y = m(:,2);

topEdge = 1; % define limits
botEdge = 0; % define limits
numBins = 2; % define number of bins

binEdges = linspace(botEdge, topEdge, numBins+1);

[h,whichBin] = histc(x, binEdges);

for i = 1:numBins
    flagBinMembers = (whichBin == i);
    binMembers     = y(flagBinMembers);
    binMean(i)     = mean(binMembers);
end
```

Comment: @MatlabDoug It might be better to do something like topEdge = max(x); botEdge = min(x); so it is clear where those numbers are coming from.