# Opposite of Binning in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to know the opposite of binning (something like over sampling),

I have less number of points on the x axis. And the curves are not very smooth when plotted against values of Yaxis. I want to find more points within lets say 2 x axis values (multiple points between 1 and 2 e.g. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) and then interpolating between(1.1, 1.2, 1.3.....2) instead of just plotting at 1 and 2) them so that the curve looks smooth and not abrupt changes. (for e.g. between 1 and 2 in this case)

In short: I need the *opposite* of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419223/binning-in-matlab).

What can I use to do this?

Comment: sounds like interpolation: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/interpolation-1.html

Answer (score 0):

You may interpolate your data.
If linear interpolate is suitable for you, try this:

```
x = [1 2];
y = 2 * x;   % y is your function related to x
new_x = x(1) : 0.1 : x(end);
new_y = interp1(x, y, new_x);
```

You can choose another alternative interpolation methods such as `'nearest'`, `'linear'`,`'spline'`,`'pchip'`, or `'cubic'`. The default method is `'linear'`.